# Is the quote of bash -c" itself only used for containing and differing the quotes of other commands inside it?

Tags: linux, bash

Update: I just realized I'm terribly wrong, I don't know how to correct though.

For example, `bash -c " echo "$S" "` and `bash -c ' echo "$S" '` will get totally different output. but my current knowledge is still not enough to conclude correctly.

---

---

the title maybe sound a little confusing,

I mean, For example, as default `bash -c ' echo " smth " '`

if `echo` requires a single quotes `'` for itself usage, `echo ' #!$smth '`

then `bash -c` will have to switch to Double quote `"` instead,  to differ `echo`'s single qutoe

so `bash -c " echo ' #!$smth ' "`

And there is no difference for `bash -c` whatever single or double
quotes.

Do I understand right or please don't hesitate correct me.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends. If we run `bash -c ...`, there's two sets of shell command line processing, once in the outer shell before the `bash -c ...` runs, and once inside it. The way we use different quotes in each determines the way expansions are made, or not made in each. Often you'd use single quotes on the outside, e.g. like `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'whatever "$1"' sh {} \;`, because with the single quotes, the outside shell doesn't touch the `$1`, but the inner shell gets to expand it with what it was given (from `find` here). But `bash -c "echo ' smth ' "` would be exactly the same either way

Comment: Please specify what you mayn by "I just realized I'm terribly wrong". If you thought better of your question, you can always delete it as long as it has no answers yet.

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks for your concern. I mean, the question, the understanding of the usage of the quotes of ```bash -c ``` is wrong, I thought it didn't matter with single or double quotes for ```bash -c``` itself , but actually it matters, it matters a lot. For example, ```bash -c " echo "$S" "``` and ```bash -c ' echo "$S" '``` will get totally different output. but my current knowledge is still not enough to conclude correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Double quoted or unquoted variables, like $S or "$S" are expanded in the current shell.   When you single quote a string, it is passed literally (minus the singe quotes) to the child process.   In your examples you have

```
...
---> parent-shell
------> child-shell (bash -c)
------> echo command executed in child shell.
```

In your first example $S is expanded in the parent shell.
In your second example $S is expanded to null in the child shell where it is undefined.
Exporting the S variable allows it to be passed to the child shell.
Example:

```
[me] S=foo
[me] bash -c " echo "$S" "
foo
[me] bash -c ' echo "$S" '

[me] export S
[me] bash -c ' echo "$S" '
foo
[me]
```